# REST client library in C

Tags: c, rest

Is there a good C library that I can use in my client application for talking to REST servers ?

Comment: did you happened to fing something better than libcurl?

Comment: No. I could not find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libcurl comes to mind, as REST is based around basic HTTP requests.

Of course this is just a starting point; you'd need to write a little logic on top of it.  I'm not sure if what you're looking for is a source-generating solution where you can point it at a service descriptor and have stubs produced automatically, or whether you're just looking for connectivity.